# prevent double query using many to many field

Tags: python, django

In my model I got this:

```
Model(models.Model):
  prices = models.ManyToManyField('Price')

  def foo(self):
    obj_prices = self.prices.all() # I expect save all prices in 'obj_prices'

    fist_price = obj_prices[0]     # I need the first price

    for obj_price in obj_prices:   # Also I need to check each price
      // Do something
```

As I commented I expect save all prices in 'obj_prices' to prevent multiple queries. But I checked this with Debug Toolbar and I got this:

```
SELECT ••• FROM `app_model` ASC LIMIT 1

SELECT ••• FROM `app_model` ASC
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QuerySets are lazy and execute only when needed. It's trying to do you a favor by only doing a LIMIT 1 on the first query.

If you're going to iterate over the queryset anyways, force it to execute:

```
obj_prices = list(self.prices.all())
```